# Using an SKAction to call a function with parameters

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I am trying to call a function via an SKAction that takes 1 input parameter.

When I declare the SKAction, I get an error: "Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '() -> Void'

```
self.run(SKAction.repeat(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1), SKAction.run(self.decreaseHealth(by: 5.0))]), count: 10))

func decreaseHealth(by amount: Double){
    print(health)
    health -= amount
    print(health)
    let percentageToDecrease = amount / totalHealth
    let resizeAction = SKAction.resize(toHeight: CGFloat(600*(1-percentageToDecrease)), duration: 1)
    let redAmount: CGFloat = CGFloat(1.0 - health / totalHealth)
    let greenAmount: CGFloat = CGFloat(health / totalHealth)
    let recolorAction = SKAction.colorize(with: UIColor(red: redAmount, green: greenAmount, blue: CGFloat(0.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0)), colorBlendFactor: 0, duration: 1)

    healthBar.run(SKAction.group([resizeAction, recolorAction]))

}
```

Comment: Why do you even need to use SKAction to run your function?

Comment: I need to use an action to run the function because I will be using it in a sequence of actions, repeating multiple times. I cannot simply call the function.

Comment: You didn't fully explain your situation.  What's the sequence of actions?  How many times do you intend to repeat the sequence?

Comment: @ElTomato I’ve edited the included code to better specify why I would like to call this function with an SKAction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

usually when you get that error, it just means you need to enclose the function inside of curly brackets. so:

`self.run(SKAction.repeat(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1), SKAction.run( { self.decreaseHealth(by: 5.0) } )]), count: 10))`

If you had split this into multiple lines, it would have been easier to spot.

this is because `decreaseHealth` is of type `()` but `{ decreasHealth }` if of type `() -> ()` or `() -> Void`

(Closures are function type in Swift, thus have parameter / arguments and returns)

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: @DanO'Leary I'm glad :) I didn't even open Xcode :P

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used SpriteKit for 3 months.  But something like the following should work.

```
func repeatMe() {
    let waitAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)
    let completionAction = SKAction.run {
        self.decreaseHealth(by: 5.0)
    }
    let seqAction = SKAction.sequence([waitAction, completionAction])
    let repeatAction = SKAction.repeat(seqAction, count: 10)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I simply switched from parentheses around the function to curly brackets.

Comment: @DanO'Leary I would write it like the above though: it would have helped you find the issue much faster. I think 1 liners are best for when you are _damn sure_ of what you are doing, and when what you are doing is just boilerplate stuff. Otherwise, a bit of verbosity can be good for maintainability and readability

Comment: @Fluidity yeah I agree that ElTomato has written it much more nicely here. I guess just laziness got the best of me.